# Как размечать изображения для нейронной сети?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, анализ-данных, обработка-изображений

Передо мной стоит задача разметить видео, которое было разбито мною на большое количество изображений, около 500-700 штук. Данные изображения будут использоваться для обучения нейронной сети. Все они однотипные, на их изображены различные датчики и шкалы. Изменяются только значения на датчиках и шкалах. Есть ли программы которые позволяет скопировать разметку с предыдущего изображения на следующее, чтобы на тратить кучу времени чтобы размечать каждое изображения с нуля? На следующем изображении может появится новый датчик, но его я размещу дополнительно. Самое главное, чтобы можно было скопировать разметку с предыдущего изображения. Посоветуйте пожалуйста программу или способ как это можно сделать.

Comment: А в чём вы собственно делаете разметку, как эта разметка выглядит вообще? И сам процесс разметки и данные, которые в результате получаются.

Comment: @CrazyElf так в этом то как раз и вопрос, в чем можно сделать разметку чтобы не нужно было каждое изображение размечать с нуля в брать разметку с предыдущего, копировать

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас то вы в чём делаете разметку вообще? И что там на выходе, в каком формате получается файл? А то может там руками можно накопипастить инфу )